# JPA - search objects by list of strings

Tags: java, jpa, orm, entity

I have entity bean like this:

```
@ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "example",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "test_id")
    )
    private List<String> tests = new ArrayList<>();
```

I need to find objects which have at least one string in list like string in another list of strings. 
For example:
Object has elements in list "One, Two, Three" 
Another list has elements "One, Four, Five"
The query should find this object, because String "One" is in both lists.

How should look a query?

Comment: if so please accept/vote it

Answer (score 1):

```
@Entity    
class Entry {

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "example",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "test_id"))
  private List<String> tests = new ArrayList<>();

   //getter setter.....

}       
  public List<Entry> getByTests(List<String> tests){
    String sql = " SELECT entry  FROM Entry entry left join fetch 
    entry.tests test left join fetch WHERE  test in(:tests) ";

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql);
    query.setParameter("tests",tests);
    return query.getResultList();
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

[Collection.retainAll(Collection c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) may be what you need. It mutates the original collection by removing all elements that are not contained within A in B, e.g:

```
List<Integer> a = ...; // a = 1,2,3,4,5
List<Integer> b = ...; // b = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
b.retainAll(a); // returns true, b becomes 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: I am looking JPA query.